# What is the worst recorded record for a team that was, the previous year, a Stanley cup finalist?

Tags: ice-hockey, records

Looking at the Habs this year is... well, pain.

And I'm starting to wonder, will they hit the 'Worst record for a team that was a Stanley cup finalist the year prior' record.

So what is that record in the NHL since it's start?

Comment: The NHL part of this is a good question; are you able to restrict/refine the "other sports" bit somewhat - I'm sure I can find some relatively obscure sport somewhere where a team was useless the next year. A similar issue applies to "finalist", especially when you move outside US sports into ones which don't have playoffs to determine the champion. That all said, 1998 Marlins.

Comment: Yes - please be very specific what you want to compare to, or this is simply too broad.   Also consider time - there are cases of "American Football champions" that went defunct the next year, and probably the same for baseball, in the "pre modern era" for those.  If you want a useful answer, you should probably define specific sports and what you consider their specific "modern era" (either Superbowl era or post-merger era for NFL, post-merger probably for NBA, MLB you could use a few different cutoffs, NHL probably post-original-six era?)

Comment: Guess the right comparative data point would be win%. But yeah I had the impression i was stretching on a limb with my 'same record in other sports' part.

Comment: @Fredy31 Just clarify what sports you mean and what time period, it's not all that hard to answer, but I don't want to spend time writing an answer that doesn't fit your particulars. :)

Comment: Closing this as needs details; please feel free to edit in the requested details and it can be reopened.

Comment: Removed the 'other sports' section because, well, it created a lot of work for a part that was not that important to the question in general.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Btw, while the Marlins are the "classic" example of this, those of us from Chicago remember the true example of first-to-worst... peek at my deleted answer if you want the hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the NHL's "modern era", The [2006-7 Hurricanes (40-35-7 OTLs, or 40-42)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006%E2%80%9307_Carolina_Hurricanes_season) had the worst record by a defending champion if you count the OTLs as losses (which the NHL doesn't exactly).  If you count OTLs as ties (or just count "points"), then the [1995-96 NJ Devils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995%E2%80%9396_New_Jersey_Devils_season) had a slightly worse winning percentage if you count ties as half-wins (but still over .500), and the [1990-91 Edmonton Oilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990%E2%80%9391_Edmonton_Oilers_season) won only half their games exactly (37-37-6) - but made the playoffs and advanced to the conference finals, so I'm not sure that is quite the same.

To find a team that was in the class of the other three leagues (the other 3 major leagues have a team around .333), you have to go all the way back *before* the original six era to the [1938-39 Chicago Blackhawks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1938%E2%80%9339_Chicago_Black_Hawks_season), who at 12-28-8 had a .300 winning percentage of non-tied games, or a .333 winning percentage if you count ties as half-wins.  However, they're sort of a special case: the [1937-1938 Hawks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1937%E2%80%9338_Chicago_Black_Hawks_season) won the championship with a record of only 14-25-9 - a .385 winning percentage counting ties as half wins!